# Select and extract contact details using Intent and ActivityResultContracts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose, android-contacts, activityresultcontracts

I have a button to open and select a contact for some of it's specific data - name and number using [ActivityResultContracts.PickContact](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts). Using the guide from [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#PickContactDat) and some modifications, I was able to retrieve the contact name successfully.

I have this in my manifest file for permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Issue is my app crashes whenever I select the contact to get it's number.

Exception thrown is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1

Can I have more knowledge about what is going on and how to make it work as intended?

```
///THE COMMENTED LINES ARE FOR CONTACT'S NAME AND IT WORKED PERFECTLY (COMMENT THE NUMBER LINES FOR TEST)

@Composable
@Preview
fun openAndSelectContact() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val launchContact = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()
    ) {

        val projection: Array<String> = arrayOf(
//            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        )


        context.contentResolver.query(
            it!!,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )
            .use { cursor ->
                if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
                      val numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
                      val number = cursor.getString(numberIndex)
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Number is $number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

//                    val nameIndex =
//                        cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
//                    val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
//                    Toast.makeText(context, "Name is $name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                        .show()

                }
            }
    }


    val launchContactPermission = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted ->
        if (isGranted) {
            launchContact.launch()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }

    }

    Button(
        content = { Text("IMPORT FROM CONTACT") },
        onClick = {
            when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //First time asking for permission ... to be granted by user
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
                ) -> {
                    launchContact.launch()
                }
                else -> {
                    //If permission has been already granted
                    launchContactPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems using  **ActivityResultContracts.PickContact()** is the issue.

I had to modify the code using **Intent** and **ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()** to get my desired result. Here is the new code

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun openAndSelectContact() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    //create a intent variable
    val contactIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply {
        type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
    }

    val launchContactForResult = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->

        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val contactUri: Uri? = result?.data?.data

            val projection: Array<String> = arrayOf(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
            )
            
            contactUri?.let {
                context.contentResolver.query(it, projection, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
                    // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number and (or) name
                    if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
                        val numberIndex =
                            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
                        val number = cursor.getString(numberIndex)

                        val nameIndex =
                            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                        // Do something with the phone number
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Number is $number & Name is $name",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val launchContactPermission = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted ->
        if (isGranted) {
            launchContactForResult.launch(contactIntent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }

    }

    Button(
        content = { Text("IMPORT FROM CONTACT") },
        onClick = {
            when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //First time asking for permission ... to be granted by user
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
                ) -> {
                    launchContactForResult.launch(contactIntent)
                }
                else -> {
                    //If permission has been already granted
                    launchContactPermission.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```